# Create a multidimensional symbolic array in Matlab 2013b

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, symbolic-math

According to the Matlab R2016a documentation, a symbolic multidimensional array can be comfortably created by using the `sym` command as follows:

```
A = sym('a',[2 2 2])
```

and the output is

```
A(:,:,1) =
[ a1_1_1, a1_2_1;
  a2_1_1, a2_2_1]

A(:,:,2) =
[ a1_1_2, a1_2_2;
  a2_1_2, a2_2_2]
```

However, I'm using Matlab 2013b and this command doesn't work for multiple dimensions. Is there any other way to create such variables for the 2013b version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not yet using R2016a, but looking around the code for the `sym` class (type `edit sym` in your Command Window), it's not too hard to write one's own function to do this:

```
function s = ndSym(x,a)
    a = a(:).';
    format = repmat('%d_',[1 numel(a)]);
    x = [x format(1:end-1)];

    s = cellfun(@createCharArrayElement,num2cell(1:prod(a)),'UniformOutput',false);
    s = sym(reshape(s,a));

    function s = createCharArrayElement(k)
        [v{1:numel(a)}] = ind2sub(a,k);
        s = sprintf(x,v{:});
    end
end
```

You can the test it via `A = ndSym('A',[2 2 2])`, which returns:

```
A(:,:,1) =

[ A1_1_1, A1_2_1]
[ A2_1_1, A2_2_1]


A(:,:,2) =

[ A1_1_2, A1_2_2]
[ A2_1_2, A2_2_2]
```

This function should work for arrays with an arbitrary number of dimensions. I tested it in R2013b and R2015b. However, note that the function above doesn't incorporate any input validation and many of the options/niceties supported by `sym`. These could be added. Also, be aware that many pre-R2016a symbolic math functions may not support such multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: Dear @horchler, Thank you for your detailed answer.